# Jelastic with hibernate config error

Tags: hibernate, jelastic

passhi plnning to deploy a spring hibernate app on jelastic cloud,And i cofigured with as my below code .After deploying tomcat throw error coanot find connection error...

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://mysql-estate.jelastic.servint.net/realestate" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="pass" />


    </bean>
```

Db:realestate
user:root
password:BRju1ky7G2

Comment: 1. You should change your root password now that you've published it on the Internet... 2. What did ServInt support say?

Comment: You misunderstood. I mean that because you posted these details, ANYONE can now access your database server via phpMyAdmin. You should change it.

Answer (score 2):

Please ,ask your hosting provider for help with this issue.

[image: Support]